# Exchange Server - Global Access

Tags: .net, outlook, exchange-server, global

I'm trying to create a web-based app that can interact with Exchange server globally.  Meaning, I need it to have the ability to view, change, delete, and create all e-mails, calendars, appointments, tasks, notes, etc... across the domain.  I am using .Net, and have been looking into sinks, but wasn't sure if this was the best route to go.  Will sinks give me the full functionality I need (It appears to only work with e-mails, though I haven't fully begin coding it yet as I'm waiting on the server to arrive)?  Or does anyone have any better suggestions / ideas?  Thanks in advance!

- Andrew Whittington

Let me elaborate a little further, I think I gave the wrong impression.  These solutions allow for a client to access their e-mail, calendar, etc... via the webmail.

I need the web-app to be able to access everyone's e-mails, calenders, etc... Not for each individual client to access their own.  The final solution will provide a way to track a team within a company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of R&D, managed sinks can sit on the exchange server, and are triggered when a save action happens in a specified folder.  If a sink was to be registered to each client's folder, it can provide a way to collect all the data, and make changes/additions where required (such as, detecting an e-mail, and triggering an appointment to be created).  Hope anyone else with a similar issue can benefit from this!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think exchange already has a webmail interface.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange does already have a webmail interface it is known as Outlook Web Access.

Another option is to use simple SMTP located in the System.Web.Mail namespace within the .net framework.

[System.Web.Mail Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.aspx)

If you are after a specific API then hopefully you are using Exchange 2007, if you are look at the

[Exchange Development on Microsofts MSDN Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/default.aspx)

Also check out this book, it may have some very useful info in it

[Exchange Web Services](http://www.amazon.ca/Inside-Microsoft-Exchange-Server-Services/dp/0735623929/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1244068432&sr=8-1)